# How many constructors can an inherited class have?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, inheritance, constructor

When I'm trying to create multiple constructors for an inherited class, I have an error throw out saying: No matching function call to A::A().
My codes are shown as below:

```
class A{  
public:  
    int a;  
    int b;  
    A(int i, int k) : a(i), b(k){  

    };  

};  

class B : public A{  
public:  
    B(){  

    };  
    B(int i, int k) : A(i, k){  
    };  


};
```

Comment: `B(){}` This has to call some constructor of the base class. Since you didn't specify which one to call in the member init list, it'll attempt to use `A()`, but it doesn't exist.

Comment: Your problem is not the number of constructors (you can, in principle, have as many as you like), it's that you are not providing the one you try to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How many constructors can an inherited class have?

The language does not impose a limit on the number of constructors whether the class inherits another or not (except if you inherit a class with no non-deleted constructors, then the child also cannot have any non-deleted constructors).

The implementation may be constrained in practice. The minimum number of maximum supported member declarations - which includes the constructors - for a single class *recommended* by the standard is 4096. Being a recommendation means that neither lower nor higher supported maximum affects whether an implementation may be considered to be standard compliant.

> No matching function call to A::A()

This is because you're trying to default initialise the base class sub object, but the base class is not default-initialisable.

There are two possible solutions:

1. Declare a default constructor so that A is default initialisable, or
2. Initialise the base class sub object using the non-default constructor. Example:

---

```
B(): A(42, 1337) {}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
B() {}
```

is equivalent to

```
B() : A() {}
```

Since `A` doesn't have a default constructor, that is a compile time error.

You can fix it by:

1. Adding a default constructor to `A`, or
2. By changing the implementation of `B`'s default constructor to use the existing constructor of `A`.

   ```
   B() : A(0, 0) {}
   ```